# C++ Binding an Index to One Data Structure

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, indexing, type-safety

Suppose I have two containers of elements:

```
std::vector<std::string> foo = { "aa", "bb", "cc" };
std::vector<std::string> bar = { "dd", "ee" };
```

I pass around indecies into `foo` and `bar` between many classes that operate on these two containers. However, I find that I have to be very careful not to confuse which indecies are associated with which container, and sometimes fail in this and then have a lot of trouble finding logical errors that result.

So, suppose I have two indecies:

```
int id_foo = 1;
int id_bar = 0;
```

Is there a simple design pattern which helps prevent cases where I try to call `bar[id_foo]` by "binding" `id_foo` to `foo`.

Basically, I'm trying to figure out the simplest way to disambiguate between `foo` and `bar`. I could create separate classes for each and then just define iterators into those classes. But I would like to avoid creating a separate class for every container like `foo` and `bar` for which I want this "safety".

The question is asking for something like "index safety" (analogous to type safety). The way I'm currently accomplishing this is by naming my indecies in such a way as to indicate which container they are associated with.

Comment: Are you able to use standard STL iterators rather than indices?

Comment: Yes, standard STL iterators are fine too, but how would I check which container the iterator is associated with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really a design pattern for differentiating what an index indexes into. There are some conventions.

You could use typedefs to differentiate them. That is, typedef an `int` to be a `FooIndex`, and similarly for a `BarIndex`. You could also use a bit of Hungarian notation for the names (I know people hate that, but this sort of thing is really what it was intended for). You already seem to be using some of it, but not in a useful way. Consider this naming convention:

```
int fooCurrentKey = 1;
int barCurrentKey = 0;
```

This lets you know that the first index is for list `foo` and the second is for list `bar`.

Comment: Thanks, Nicol. Javier had a few interesting points above but they really missed the precise thing I was asking and I believe from your comments and your answer that you got it. Thanks for your help. It's nice to see so many brilliant people part of SO. By the way, I do in fact use a variation of Hungarian notation but prefer to separate the type specifier with an underscore.

Answer (score -1):

No need to set different classes, just use iterators instead of indices.  It will go to the appropriate element, since it already knows which container to look into (if necessary).

Comment: One thing to keep in mind regarding iterators vs indices, is that if OP ever grows their container, the iterators will be invalidated, while the indices would not.  But aside from that minor point, with `std::advance` and `std::difference` you can do everything with iterators that you could do before with indices.

Comment: @Javier, how would I check which container the iterator is associated with?

Comment: And also, the issue that @Lambdageek brings up is crucial to me. If a container grows will an iterator remain valid?

Comment: not all iterators allow it (since a raw pointer is a valid iterator for a raw array); but you could: a) not care, just reference the iterator and you'll get to the element,  b) if you're using specific containers, you'll get specific iterator classes, and those might implement the needed call.  or c) don't pass around an iterator, pass an object with both an iterator and container references.  in most cases, option A is best, but you might have to rethink the way you access elements.  for example, most STL algorithms don't take a container, just a begin/end iterator pair.

Comment: @Lex Fridman: You don't; most if not all release-mode iterators have no idea what containers they are attached to. Debug-mode ones only know to help debug your code. Using iterators to differentiate these is bad advice, so -1.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: that's exactly what i'm saying: the iterator knows if it needs to, so you don't.